# Need a query to show first and last name of how many games refs officiated

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT p.first_name as [First Name],
    p.last_name as [Last Name],
     count (game.refID) as [Num Games]

FROM referee r LEFT JOIN person p
ON r.PersonID = p.PersonId 
INNER JOIN game 
ON p.PersonId = game.refID
group by first_name
```

MY error is a "aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."  Can anyone help me make this work, where it shows first and last name with the Count Command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must show in group by all the column noy involved  in aggregation function

```
  SELECT p.first_name as `First Name` 
    , p.last_name as `Last Name`
    , count(game.refID) as `Num Games`
  FROM referee r 
  LEFT JOIN person p ON r.PersonID = p.PersonId 
  INNER JOIN game  ON p.PersonId = game.refID
  group by p.first_name,  p.last_name
  order by count(game.refID) DESC
```

PS For alias column name with with more than a single word  you could use backtics

Comment: If I wanted the num games to be Descending how would I write that query?

Comment: answer  updated ..  .. but this mean that your error is solved ..  right?

Comment: Use `ORDER BY count(game.refID) DESC`

Answer (score 0):

Your query is too complicated.  I don't think you need the `referee` table:

```
SELECT p.first_name as [First Name], p.last_name as [Last Name],
       COUNT(*) as [Num Games]
FROM person p INNER JOIN
     game g
     ON p.PersonId = g.refID
GROUP BY p.first_name, p.last_name;
```